# How to initialize useform checkboxes with values from registry

Tags: excel, vba, registry, userform

I have a checkbox on my userform. When I click it, the value is set to "True" and the setting is stored in registry. When I uncheck it, its being set to "False" and setting again is set in registry.

The code for check box click event:

```
Dim CheckBox_Check As String
CheckBox_Check = GetSetting(appname:="APPLICATION", section:="SECTION", Key:="CHECKBOXKEY")

If CheckBox_Check = False Then
    CheckBox.Value = True
    SaveSetting "APPLICATION", "SECTION", "CHECKBOXKEY", "True"
    Exit Sub
ElseIf CheckBox_Check = True Then
    CheckBox.Value = False
    SaveSetting "APPLICATION", "SECTION", "CHECKBOXKEY", "False"
    Exit Sub
End If
```

The code above works well, but I have a great issue with initializing the userform with checkbox setting (true or false). When I use the following code on userform_initialize:

```
CheckBox.Value = GetSetting(appname:="APLIKACJA", section:="SECTION", Key:="CHECKBOXKEY")
```

Then when it needs to set checkbox to true, it goes all the way through "checkbox click" sub, and it simply does not work. Userform initializes only with false values.

Can somebody help me sort it out? I am trying to achieve the following goals:

1) To be able to set checkbox to "checked" "unchecked" and store those settings in registry.

2) Initialize userform with "checked" "unchecked" status based on registry values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this approach, please:

```
Sub testValFromRegistry()
Dim strInit As String
   strInit = GetSetting("APLIKACJA", "SECTION", "CHECKBOXKEY", "No settings...")
   Application.EnableEvents = False
    If strInit = "No settings..." Then
         CheckBox.value = False
    Else
         CheckBox.value = CBool(strInit)
    End If
   Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

You write "True" in Registry, which is a `String`. It must be transformed in `Boolean`... Otherwise, it is all the time `False`.

Comment: Thanks for help. I have tried the code above but it does not work. I mean, it works, but it goes through the checkbox click event, just like my original code... It could help, but I was not able to modify my click event macro to make it check and uncheck the checkbox. The only solution I have is the one in the original post.

Comment: @Rafał Kowalski: Would you like to trigger the event, or to avoid triggering when the value is changed? In order to avoid it you must use my updated code. In order to make it be triggered, theoretically it is nothing to be done, except the case you make EnableEvents `False` at the beginning of the the Intitialize Event. Try exactly viceversa, please. I mean, firstly `True` and secondly `False`...

Comment: @Rafał Kowalski: If ti still does  not work as expected (normally, I mean), please check if the CheckBox event does not change another control which (by mistake) changes back the check box value...

Comment: @Rafał Kowalski: I do use the Registry values for a lot of controls and I proceed as I tried showing you in my code. But if it does not work for you, I will delete my answer...